# How to change session cookie path in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-session

I want to change session cookie path in ZF2. By default it is `/` I want to change it on `/my_path/`
I tried to do it with SessionManager

```
$config = new \Zend\Session\Config\StandardConfig();
$config->setOptions(array(
    'cookie_path' => '/my_path/',
));
$sessionManager = new \Zend\Session\SessionManager($config);
\Zend\Session\Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);
$sessionManager->start();
```

But it does not work

---

Resolve:
change first line on `$config = new \Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not enough to just create the session manager, you also need to tell the session containers about it, the `Container` class has a static method to do that. Add the following line to your code

```
    \Zend\Session\Container::setDefaultManager($sessionManager);
```

Comment: Are you actually starting the session after that using `$sessionManager->start();`

Comment: If I change first line on $config = new \Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig(); then it works fine